# Creating a sortable header with a filter in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the Datatable plugin for jQuery to create a sortable header and filter above it. The screenshot below shows what I need.

I'd like the filter to be at the top of the header. I've tried using `display: table-header-group;` using css, but that doesn't work in IE.

How would I fix this?
[image]

Comment: This might help you http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/ukCaB

Comment: @Gaurav thanks but this is default data table. But I need the same functionality as attached the screenshot with filter and sorting.

Comment: [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) i can't move the filter above the header sort.